# Deploying Windows forms application with Config

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to deploy a windows forms application which uses the properties/settings of the project to store config information.
In a form it is retrieved and sometimes changed by saving as below

```
 Properties.Settings.Default["name"] = textBox1.Text;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I only need to deploy to 3 PCS. Is it enough to deploy the .exe file alone?
Or do I also need the exe.config file ?

Thanks

Comment: If you can deploy using the publish option in Visual Studio then this becomes a non-issue. It would also make it a lot easier to subsequently update the application, if necessary.

Comment: @Tinwor Databases are for data, App.config is for configuration. There is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your `App.config1` file contains default configuration information not embedded in your program, such as a connection string, then yes, you will need to bundle it with your executable.

However the code you've posted shows you're using the "Settings" feature, which is a feature of .NET that runs on-top of `App.config`. If you use the Settings feature, then your app.config file is (usually) actually stored under your current user's AppData directory and not the same directory as the executable, these files are also created as-required, in which case you won't need to ship the app.config file... assuming you have nothing else in the file.